# Problem with bearerAuth type authorization when using openapi code generator using a maven project and a input YAML

Tags: java, yaml, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I have a input spec YAML file, I am using it to generate the client code -

This is what I have tried ->

1. I tried [www.editor.swagger.io](http://www.editor.swagger.io), gave me a GUI, when I clicked on Authorize, I got 2 ways -> Basic Auth and Beaer Auth using a access token -> Working fine (Just to test the design)
2. When I generated the code using swagger code gen maven, works fine.

**BUT**

When I am using openapi code gen using maven to generate client code, I am not getting bearerAuth part,

I have a method called setAccessToken() --> If you see when setAccessToken is called, it is directly throwing exception when i generated code using openApi

```
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No OAuth2 authentication configured!");
    }
```

When I am using swagger code gen...I am not getting this problem...as you can see below the code is getting generated correctly

```
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        for (Authentication auth : authentications.values()) {
            if (auth instanceof OAuth) {
                ((OAuth) auth).setAccessToken(accessToken);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No OAuth2 authentication configured!");
    }
```

This is how my YAML looks...

```
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
security:
  - basicAuth: []
  - bearerAuth: []
```

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues or see if there's an existing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check setBearerAuth() api, there should be one more instead of setAccessToken. I had same issue.

Comment: Yes, it was the case.